# Javascript Popup Yes and No Dialog Window inside of a PHP Document

Tags: javascript, php

I currently have a **index.php** document that sends data the **login.php**

document with the values:

1. studentid
2. firstname
3. lastname.

   What I wanted to do is create a **yes / no** dialog box appear before submitting the data into my database.  Here is the code I wrote:

   **THEY ARE NOT IN THE DATABASE YET SO STORE THEM**

   ```
     $readStr1 = 'Are you sure you want to create a user account under this email address?';
     echo '
     <script>
       var r = window.confirm("'.$readStr1.'");
       if (r==true)
         'mysql_query("INSERT INTO `persons` (studentid,firstname,lastname,paid) VALUES ('".$studentid."','".$firstname."','".$lastname."','0')") or die(mysql_error());';
     } else {
       history.back();
     }
     </script>
     ';
   ```

I already know the variables and everything are working since I can submit the data into the **sql database** fine without the echo code.

However once I added that, the entire page is just blank with no console output whatsoever and no **javascript** popup window appears.

Thanks for the help and hope I gave enough information :)

Comment: JavaScript cannot run php/MySQL code. You need to use Ajax to sent a request to a php to run the code

Comment: Change it to put the confirm box on the client side, before the data is sent to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why blank

Your php has syntax error. Do not forget string join operator:

```
$a=world;
echo 'hello,'.$a.'!';
```

## Important

You should know how php works First!
 1. When you visit a .php page, server will interpret php to render a html document.
 2. When render complete, server send the html document to browser.
 3. When browser receive complete, browser start to interpret the document. And javascript program start run.

Php is a server-side langauage,and js is a client-side, they run at different time.PHP generate js code first(on server),and js run second(on browser).

So, you cam try ajax. Send the confirm condition to another php file, let that file run query statment:

```
echo '
<script>
var r = window.confirm("'.$readStr1.'");
if (r==true)
      insert();
} else {
    history.back();
}
function insert(){
    // write some ajax code
}
</script>
';
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Your explanation was excellent and I'm a new web developer so I didn't know this previously.